# Stop outlook.com automatically marking emails as read when clicked

Tags: outlook.com

How do I stop outlook.com marking emails as read when I click on them?

You can change this setting in the Outlook desktop applications but not in outlook.com .

Comment: Appears messages are marked read when clicked by design.  At least as of 9/11/12. [via Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/how-do-you-stop-outlookcom-from-marking-messages/45596d60-8d9a-4fd8-85c7-66088ad6c01a?msgId=c18be7cb-7b90-4836-8526-2145c4e9fbe3)